# Meromorphic section of a subbundle

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

I have recently been trying to extend my knowledge of complex analysis by expanding to Riemann surface theory. I had been recommended Forster's Lectures on Riemann Surfaces as a good reference to go through and have been doing some of the exercises. The most recent exercise I have attempted has had me scratching my head, namely exercise 29.1. Admittedly I do not have a lot of experience in dealing with vector bundles so I think my intuition is off about how to approach this problem.

First, a definition:

> Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $\pi: E \to X$ a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $n$ on $X$. A holomorphic subbundle $F \subseteq E$ of rank $k$ is a subset such that the following holds. For every $x \in X$ there exists a holomorphic local trivialisation
> $$h: E_U \to U \times \mathbb{C}^n, \qquad E_U = \pi^{-1}(U),$$
> of $E$ with $x \in U$ such that
> $$h(F_U) = U \times (\mathbb{C}^k \times 0)$$
> where $F_U = E_U \cap F$.

**My problem is that given a meromorphic section $f$ of $E$, I need to show that there exists a unique subbundle $F$ of rank 1 such that $f$ is a meromorphic section of $F$.** I do know from the previous part of the exercise that if I am given a holomorphic section that never vanishes, then I can construct a holomorphic subbundle of rank 1. To do this, I need only to look at this locally, and so then the problem becomes constructing $h$ as an invertible linear transformation sending the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ to a basis including the vector $(f_1, \dots, f_n)$, the local representation of $f$. To tackle my current problem, I was thinking that I should somehow cunningly choose an open neighbourhood of $X$ so that the problem becomes easier to deal with, and then somehow use this result to obtain a subbundle of rank 1. However, I am unsure how to make any of this precise nor do I know how to proceed to show that such a subbundle is unique.

Any guidance would be much appreciated but I would like to add that I cannot use very heavy or "sophisticated" machinery. In particular, I can't use anything beyond Riemann surface theory that has not been presented in Forster, because I believe he has made these exercises possible to be completed with general undergraduate complex analysis knowledge or from the material that he has presented. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just a quick note: The idea is to use the points where the section is finite and non-zero to define $F$ away from finitely many points (the zeros and poles of $f$), then at each zero or pole $z_0$ to write the section locally in the form $$a_k(z-z_0)^k + \cdots = (z - z_0)^k(a_k + \cdots),$$the dots indicating higher-order terms. The expression in parentheses on the right is a finite, non-vanishing local section that defines the same subbundle as $F$ away from $z_0$, and therefore extends $F$ to $z_0$. This is written up carefully elsewhere on-site, but good search terms fail me.

Comment: Could the start of a careful argument be the following? Choose a neighbourhood $U$ in $X$ such that it contains a single zero (or pole) $z_0$ of the section $f$. Then the set $F = \bigcup_{x \in U \setminus \{z_0\}} F_x$, where $F_x = \mathbb{C} \cdot f(x)$ is a holomorphic subbundle of $E$ or rank 1. Rewriting $f$ as it's Laurent series, where we mean that each $n$-tuple of $f$ is rewritten in this way, we factor out the largest possible power of $(z - z_0)$. Then as you say, the remaining series gives a non-vanishing holomorphic section. However I don't see why it defines the same subbundle?

Comment: Yes, that looks good! <> Except at $z_0$, the sections $f$ and $(z-z_0)^{-k}f$ are mutually proportional, so pointwise they span the same complex line.

Comment: I apologise if I'm missing something blatantly obvious, but could you clarify a little further?

Comment: It may help to "look backward": A local _non-vanishing holomorphic_ section $g$ determines a local line bundle. If we multiply $g$ by a meromorphic function $\phi$ having an isolated zero or pole at $z_0$, then $f := \phi g$ determines the same section away from $z_0$ because $f$ and $g$ are proportional except at $z_0$.

Comment: Right, so really I should be thinking of this as simply a complex number multiplying $g$ except at $z_0$?